# ASP.NET Core publish and launch settings

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a ASP.NET Core (v2.0) and I'm looking to retain my `launchSettings.json` properties across different environments.

The issue I'm experiencing is whenever I publish my project with `dotnet publish`, my artifacts folder containing the published output does not contain a `launchSettings.json` file. Does this compile into something else?

Answer (score 3):

`launchSettings.json` is a setting for IDE (Visual Studio, Visual Studio Code, Rider and so on), it's not used for release package.

In the `launchSettings.json` it has set up about the Environment Variable, Port and so on.

You can easier to change its (port, runtime config) on different Environment by "Computer Environment" and Command Parameters.

You can see more about [the parameter or how it affects in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

If you actually wanna change the "setting for IDE" on difference Environment, it depends on how the IDE support you.
I use Rider and it has setting for project/sln on different computer.

Answer (score 1):

Launch settings is will not be there in artifacts folder. It's a reference to solution environment variable. In cloud we can also say App Settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use environment variable `ASPNETCORE_URLS`.

## Example for Linux/Unix:

```sh
ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://0.0.0.0:5000" ./Release/netcoreapp3.1/WebApplication1
```